# How to customize partial sum in QlikView Pivot table

Tags: set, pivot-table, analysis, qlikview, subtotal

I'm a beginner for QlikView. I learnt that by going to presentation tab and click on show partial sum box and subtotal box, I can get the partial sum and subtotal. But my task is to calculate the average which means (subtotal/no of record)/ (partial sum/no of record). I've been suggested to use set analysis to calculate too. I have somehow calculated the numerator part but unable to get denominator.

This is my numerator :

```
Let vNumerator = 'SUM({<ACTIVITY={num1,num2}>} BOX_COUNT)/Count (record1 & record2)';
```

[image: Pivot table]
[image: Presentation tab]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you you want the answer to be, can you post an exel based pic of it? But an experienced guess says your dimensions are what are are tripping you up. The dimensions are determining that you end up with 1/1 for each line so just get back your numerator. You would need to use either the ALL or TOTAL option in your denominator expression. Which one depends on what you want the answer to be.

Comment: =(((Sheet1!AD83+Sheet1!AD113+Sheet1!AD143)/3)/((Sheet1!BR83+Sheet1!BR113+Sheet1!BR143)/3)) is how I calculate average in excel. What is the difference between ALL and Total option? Sorry, I'm totally new to qlikview. I want to sum up all 'SUM({<ACTIVITY={num1,num2}>} BOX_COUNT)' across A and B according to same record and divide by number of record to get average.

Comment: If you can put up some sample data and an expected outcome this doesn't seem too difficult. i can't post a picture in the comments so please see the one I put in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

From this scrap data

`load * inline [
A,B,C,D,E
1,21,a,b,z,x
2,22,b,b,z,x
3,23,a,a,x,z
4,24,b,b,x,z
5,25,b,a,x,x
6,21,a,b,z,x
7,22,b,b,z,x
8,23,a,a,x,z
9,24,b,b,x,z
10,25,b,a,x,x
11,21,a,b,z,x
12,22,b,b,z,x
13,23,a,a,x,z
14,24,b,b,x,z
15,25,b,a,x,x
16,21,a,b,z,x
17,22,b,b,z,x
18,23,a,a,x,z
19,24,b,b,x,z
20,25,b,a,x,x
];`

Which of these tables is what you are looking for out of the data?

All of these by defining a third expression as a combination of the others rather than trying to force it into an automatic subtotal.

[image: Examples]

Or make a table that shows the answers you want and post a picture of it. Even in excel is fine.

Also please let me know if I'm a million miles off the track here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum over ACTIVITY you need to use the following syntax:

```
sum( TOTAL<ACTIVITY> _your_expression_with_Set_ananaysis_ )
/
count( TOTAL<ACTIVITY> record1 & record2 )
```